# Compare loans with various interest rates java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am new to Java and just now started with loops.

I have tried to do this exercise:

Write a program that lets the user enter the loan amount and loan period in number of years and displays the monthly and total payments for each interest rate starting from 5% to 8%, with an increment of 1/8.

So far this what i have got:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class compareLoansWithInterestRates {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Loan Amount :");
    
    int loan = input.nextInt();
    
    System.out.print("Number of Years" );
    
    int years = input.nextInt();
    
    
    
    double  monthPay, totalPay,interestRate; 
    
System.out.println( "Interest Rate \t Monthly Payment \t Total Payment");
    
     for(double rate =0.05; rate <=0.08; rate++ ){
         for (int month = 1; month <= (years*12);month++){
        rate +=1/8;     
             monthPay = loan* rate/(1-(Math.pow(1+rate,years*12)));
             totalPay = monthPay*years*12;
             interestRate= rate*100;
             System.out.println("\t"+interestRate+" \t "+monthPay+"\t"+totalPay);
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code briefly, you're incrementing rate within your 'outer for' loop using rate++ (which will increment by 1, not 0.01).  You then increment rate again within the month loop by 1/8.  Try removing 'rate++' from the outer loop.  Not positive this will fix all your issues, but this is just a quick observation.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start…

First of all: Java:

```
for(double rate =0.05; rate <=0.08; rate++ ){
```

this is good for int, not for double

```
rate +=1/8;
```

1/8 is much more then 0.125% you are looking for. It's not Java, but mathematics.

The second line should not be here at all, and for loop should be:

```
for(double rate =0.05; rate <=0.08; rate+=0.00125 ){
```

Unfortunately, your algorithm seems to be wrong too, so this change won't fix everything. But from Java point of view it will be rather ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think this'll work

```
 for (double i = 5; i <= 8; i += 0.125) {
        double rate = i / 100;
        monthPay = loan * (Math.pow(1 + (rate / 12), years * 12)) / 12;
        totalPay = monthPay * years * 12;
        interestRate = i;
        System.out.println("\t" + interestRate + " \t " + monthPay + "\t" + totalPay);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simple loan calculator which is slightly different from yours, to show you just how much work goes into the input and output of a Java application.

Here's the input and output.

```
Loan Amount 60000
Number of Months 60
Yearly Interest Rate 6
 
Payments on a $60,000.00 loan for 60 months

          Monthly Payment  Total Payment
 4.000%         $1,104.99     $66,299.48
 4.250%         $1,111.77     $66,706.40
 4.500%         $1,118.58     $67,114.87
 4.750%         $1,125.41     $67,524.88
 5.000%         $1,132.27     $67,936.44
 5.250%         $1,139.16     $68,349.54
 5.500%         $1,146.07     $68,764.18
 5.750%         $1,153.01     $69,180.37
 6.000%         $1,159.97     $69,598.09
 6.250%         $1,166.96     $70,017.34
 6.500%         $1,173.97     $70,438.13
 6.750%         $1,181.01     $70,860.46
 7.000%         $1,188.07     $71,284.31
 7.250%         $1,195.16     $71,709.70
 7.500%         $1,202.28     $72,136.61
 7.750%         $1,209.42     $72,565.06
 8.000%         $1,216.58     $72,995.02
```

Here's the code that does the actual loan calculation to get the monthly amount.

```
private double calculateMonthlyPayment(double interestRate) {
    double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 12D;
    double numerator = (double) loanAmount * (monthlyInterestRate);
    double denominator = Math.pow(1 + (monthlyInterestRate),
            (double) -months);
    denominator = 1D - denominator;
    return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Pretty straightforward, right.

Now, I'm going to show you all of the code that gathered the input and produced the output.  It's way longer than just the calculation.  Go through the code as best you can, and I'll explain it as best I can.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InterestRateCalculator implements Runnable {

    private static final NumberFormat CF = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private static final NumberFormat NF = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

    private double interestRate;

    private int loanAmount;
    private int months;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getInputs();
        produceOutputs();
    }

    public void getInputs() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Loan Amount ");
        loanAmount = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Number of Months ");
        months = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Yearly Interest Rate ");
        interestRate = input.nextDouble();
        input.close();
    }

    public void produceOutputs() {
        double[] interestRates = new double[17];

        double interestRate = this.interestRate - 2.0D;
        for (int i = 0; i < interestRates.length; i++) {
            interestRates[i] = interestRate / 100D;
            interestRate += 0.25D;
        }

        String header = displayHeader();
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(header);

        System.out.print(leftPad(" ", 10, ' '));
        System.out.print(leftPad("Monthly Payment", 15, ' '));
        System.out.println(leftPad("Total Payment", 15, ' '));

        for (int i = 0; i < interestRates.length; i++) {
            String s = displayInterestRate(interestRates[i]) + "   ";
            System.out.print(leftPad(s, 10, ' '));
            double monthlyPayment = calculateMonthlyPayment(interestRates[i]);
            System.out.print(leftPad(CF.format(monthlyPayment), 15, ' '));
            double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * months;
            System.out.print(leftPad(CF.format(totalPayment), 15, ' '));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private double calculateMonthlyPayment(double interestRate) {
        double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 12D;
        double numerator = (double) loanAmount * (monthlyInterestRate);
        double denominator = Math.pow(1 + (monthlyInterestRate),
                (double) -months);
        denominator = 1D - denominator;
        return numerator / denominator;
    }

    private String displayHeader() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("Payments on a ");
        builder.append(CF.format(loanAmount));
        builder.append(" loan for ");
        builder.append(NF.format(months));
        builder.append(" months");
        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String displayInterestRate(double interestRate) {
        return String.format("%.3f", interestRate * 100D) + "%";
    }

    private String leftPad(String s, int length, char padChar) {
        if (s.length() > length) {
            return s.substring(0, length);
        } else if (s.length() == length) {
            return s;
        } else {
            int padding = length - s.length();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(padding);

            for (int i = 0; i < padding; i++) {
                builder.append(padChar);
            }
            builder.append(s);

            return builder.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InterestRateCalculator().run();
    }

}
```

The first thing that I did was use the InterestRateCalculator class as a Java object.  My static main method consists of one line.

```
        new InterestRateCalculator().run();
```

This line does two things.  It creates an instance of the InterestRateCalculator class and it executes the run method of the class.

It may seem strange now, but getting away from static methods and static fields allows you to create complex Java applications with many, many classes.  You should learn this now, while you're writing simple applications.

I implemented Runnable because a Runnable class requires a run() method.  It's a personal preference of mine.  You could have named the run() method execute(), or some other meaningful name.

I didn't write a constructor.  I used the default constructor of InterestRateCalculator();

Looking now at the run() method, I divided the problem into two parts.  Reading or getting the input and producing the output.  This allows me to focus on a smaller, simpler problem than the original problem.  This is called divide and conquer.

Getting the input is straightforward.  I copied your code and made the prompt text consistent.  I added a space at the end of each prompt so the prompts and responses would look better.  I know this sounds silly, but I assure you that I spent the better part of my programming career making changes to the appearance of the input and output of applications.

Getting the output to line up took a large part of the code to produce the output.  Producing the output was more complicated than gathering the input.  I broke the process down into many methods.  A method should do one thing, and return one output, like the calculateMonthlyPayment I showed you earlier.

I used a trick that I learned in the olden times of Cobol programming to produce the output.  I left padded the Strings I created with spaces.  You don't have to memorize this particular trick.  Other "tricks" have been gathered together and called design patterns.  Don't worry about learning any patterns right now.  Just know that they exist so that you can group code into higher levels.

I hope this explanation was helpful to you.  I know you wanted to write the code yourself.  That's why I solved a different problem than yours.

Answer (score -1):

monthpay is incorrect

```
monthPay = loan* rate/(1-1/(Math.pow(1+rate,years*12)))
```